# Searching for string data in multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Good morning,

I put together a statement that works with single string searching.  I wanted to know if its possible to retrieve multiple string data from different rows in a single search.  I created the statement on sql management studio, I then modified it so in our program it prompts the user to enter the order number they are looking for in the row.

```
SELECT HID, INumber, SlsrdrNmbr, ShpNm, CustomerNumber, InvoiceDate, BlncD,Comments
FROM dbo._adhoc_Inv
WHERE BillNumber = '512315'
AND Comments LIKE '%{{enter D}}%'
```

prompt pops up
*user enters number* D-12313

Ideally I would like for them to enter multiple numbers, because they need to match the D numbers with our internal set of the numbers we have in our system.

So this works just fine, brings up the data I want.  I want to make it easier by showing multiple search results so they don't need to close the window and search again.  Is is possible to do what I am looking for? I am still a bit of a novice.

I would like to add if I add multiple D numbers that are on the SAME row, results will show since its the same row being retrieved.

Thank you

Comment: `'D-12313'` is a strange value for a column called `comments`.

Comment: yeah data entry did some odd approach to this and its biting them in the butt now because our software cant search by comment fields.